# Rails - why does one work and not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a seeds.rb file and for some reason, this doesn't work:

```
#doesn't work
u=User.new
u['email']=h['email']
u['password']=h['password']
puts u['email']
puts u['password']
if u.save
  puts "that saved"
else
  puts "that did not save"
end
```

but this does:

```
#does work
User.create({:email => h['email'], :password => h['password']})
```

Is there any reason one works and one doesn't? From rails console, the first does work? Would there be any differences in validations? I run 'rake db:seed' so would think validations would be in effect in both.

thx

**edit #1**
sorry for lack of info. each one errors with "password can't be blank" but it then echoes out the password. Hmm...

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?"  Is there an error, or does it just not save? If the latter, check the contents of `u.errors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out what's happening by looking at the validation errors:

```
else
  puts "that did not save because " + u.errors.join(' ')
end
```

**Edit:** Now that you've added that validation errors contain `'password cant be blank'` and it still fails to save, it becomes clear that `User.create()` does a number of things which `User.save()` omits.

What's missing is the *generation of your password hash* - hence the `blank password` error.

Comment: each one errors with "password can't be blank" but then proceeds to echo out the password.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
u = User.new
u.email = h['email']
u.password = h['password']
puts u.inspect
if u.save!
  puts "that saved"
else
  puts "that did not save"
end
```

I believe the approach of accessing the attribute on the `u` object as `u['password']` is steering you wrong.

Also, doing a `u.inspect` prints the entire state of the model and that should provide a cleaner way of seeing what's happening. Finally, adding a bang `!` at the end of the save will cause it to 'fail fast' and give you the error immediately.